# Benchmarking on Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: transactions, blockchain, hyperledger

Is there any public benchmarking code and results for Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 blockchain?
IBM claims a transactions rate of 3500 tps, but I am not able to find any public code of the benchmarking experiments.
Paper link: https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.10228

Answer (score 1):

You can run `Hyperledger Caliper` https://www.hyperledger.org/projects/caliper/ , a benchmarking tool that supports Hyperledger Fabric (IBM), Hyperledger Sawtooth, Ethereum, and other blockchains.

Click on "Get the Code" link in the link above, or go to https://github.com/hyperledger/caliper for source code. It's thousands of lines of code, including benchmark blockchain apps, so that's too much to post. The original link above has documentation and is the main Caliper project page.

Comment: Just FYI, if the code is open-source and has a GitHub repo, you may want to link to it, and perhaps provide a short piece of code relevant to the question, if possible.  Short, link-only answers tend to suffer from link-rot, and become unhelpful.

Comment: That's the kind off detail it would be useful to have in the answer... use the [edit] link.  Cheers!